# Salesforce FuelSDK-Node DataExtensionRow.post error "Error: Non-whitespace before first tag"

Tags: node.js, salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am trying to insert a new "row" using [SalesForce Node SDK](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Node). In particular the `dataExtensionRow.post` method. It is currently formed as follows:

```
client.dataExtensionRow({
   Name: 'Extension_Name',
   CustomerKey: '1234',
   props: [
      { Name: 'First Name', Value: 'John' }
   ]
});
```

However I keep getting the returned error `Error: Non-whitespace before first tag`. My assumption is my data is not formatted correctly, but I cannot seem to determine where.

I have tried reorganizing the request in various fashions - Looking at the NPM package itself I cannot determine what else to try. As the method in the packaged looks like this:

```
DataExtensionRow.prototype.post = function(cb) {

    var flds = [];
    for (key in this.config.props) {
        flds.push({"Name" : key, "Value" : this.config.props[key]});
    }
    if (this.config.CustomerKey) this.props.CustomerKey = this.config.CustomerKey;
    if (this.config.Name) this.props.Name = this.config.Name;
    this.props.Properties = {};
    this.props.Properties.Property = flds;
    this.parent.SoapClient.create(
        this.objName,
        this.props,
        this.options,
        cb
    );
};
```

**Update**
After tracing the issue through dependent node modules - it turns out the request package is returning "Bad Request".

Here is the body of the request

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">\n' +
      '  <Body>\n' +
      '    <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">\n' +
      '      <Options/>\n' +
      '      <Objects xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">\n' +
      '        <CustomerKey>1234</CustomerKey>\n' +
      '        <Name>DEV Solver Customer Data</Name>\n' +
      '        <Properties>\n' +
      '          <Property>\n' +
      '            <Name>0</Name>\n' +
      '            <Value>\n' +
      '              <Name>FirstName</Name>\n' +
      '              <Value>Nicholas</Value>\n' +
      '            </Value>\n' +
      '          </Property>\n' +
      '          <Property>\n' +
      '            <Name>joinObjAddrs</Name>\n' +
      '            <Value>function() {&#xD;\n' +
      "    var ret = '';&#xD;\n" +
      '    //for(var key in this) {&#xD;\n' +
      '    for (var i=0, len=this.length; i&lt;len; i++) {&#xD;\n' +
      "        ret += '[' + this[i] + ']';&#xD;\n" +
      '    }&#xD;\n' +
      '    return ret;&#xD;\n' +
      '}</Value>\n' +
      '          </Property>\n' +
      '        </Properties>\n' +
      '      </Objects>\n' +
      '    </CreateRequest>\n' +
      '  </Body>\n' +
      '  <Header>\n' +
      '    <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">MY_AUTH_TOKEN</fueloauth>\n' +
      '  </Header>\n' +
      '</Envelope>
```

Maybe the `joinObjAddrs` key value pair being injected is the the issue?